# How to compile Autodock Vina in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, boost, bioinformatics

I'm trying to compile Autodock Vina on Visual Studio and having trouble figuring out how to do that. I would be thankful if someone can guide me through the process!

Comment: Are you encountering errors from Visual Studio when compiling? If so, post them in your question.

Comment: It's just I can't figure out how to do it; I added the boost references, but VS is saying it can't find the references for some reason and the project doesn't build! :(

Comment: I retagged as [tag:visual-studio] since it seems related to your problem, you should update the question with error messages that are relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the bellow instructions:

1- Download Boos 1.41.0 from the following link:
              http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.41.0/boost_1_41_0.zip/download

AutoDock Vina is compatible with Boost 1.41.0

2- Extract the Zip file in your computer:

- go to Boost Directory and open cmd and run the following command: bootstrap.bat
- After finish the previous step, run the following commands based on your OS:
- 32 Bit: bjam --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage
- 64 Bit: bjam --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage
                      This step takes time! (For me about 45 min).

3- Download the AutoDock Vina from the following link:
                  http://vina.scripps.edu/download/autodock_vina_1_1_2.tgz

4- Extract the folder on your machine.

5- Up to now, the Boost is installed on your machine and you have the Vina code. You should configure the VS 2010 to use it.

You can find the VS configuration in my Google Site bellow:

https://sites.google.com/site/mkoohim/stories/how-can-compile-autodock-vina-in-visual-studio

Hope this help you!